# Properly casting a string key argument to put in Intent

Tags: java, android

I need to dynamically add extras to an intent based on the size of an array. I tried concatenating the name of the key with the value of the counter but to no avail

```
for(int i = 0; i < pos_list.size(); i++) {
    int pos = pos_list.get(i);
    String EXTRA_NAME = "DetailActivityFragment.EXTRA_NAME_" + Integer.toString(i);
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, tablet_list[pos].getTabletName());
}
```

Anyway I could get this to work? Is it even possible?

Comment: "DetailActivityFragment.EXTRA_NAME_" seems like a constant, but you are using it as a string that says "DetailActivityFragment.EXTRA_NAME_", this is intentional?

Comment: @milez I defined a bunch of const strings in DetailActivityFragment to be used as keys. I'm basically trying to achieve the effect of calling putExtra(DetailActivityFragment.EXTRA_NAME_0, ...), putExtra(DetailActivityFragment.EXTRA_NAME_1,...) etc with the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that this piece of code is prone to is on this line

```
String EXTRA_NAME = "DetailActivityFragment.EXTRA_NAME_" + Integer.toString(i);
```

Since you are using `" "` your key becomes literally `DetailActivityFragment.EXTRA_NAME_n` where `n` is an integer. Since DetailActivityFragment contains a bunch of constants, you should remove `" "` to actually access them

```
String EXTRA_NAME = DetailActivityFragment.EXTRA_NAME_ + Integer.toString(i);
```

Also make sure when you are retrieving the values you either use `" "` if you used them when putting values or do not use them if you wish to use the static values defined in the `Fragment`.

EDIT: Since `DetailActivityFragment` contains several fields and you wish to retrieve those based on the `Integer`, a potential solution would be to create `get()` methods for them inside `DetailActivityFragment`. For example in that `Fragment` define (you might also need to make this `static` unless you could reference an object of your fragment instead of static reference)

```
public String getExtraName(int index)
{
   if (index == 0)
{
    return EXTRA_NAME_0;
} else if (index == 1)
{
    return EXTRA_NAME_1;
} //etc
}
```

and now when you put your extras do

```
String EXTRA_NAME = DetailActivityFragment.getExtraName(i);
```

and when you retrieve values use the same method for getting keys.

Another solution would be to use a `Map<Integer, String>` to retrieve the values. What you originally tried to do is (as far as I know) called *reflection* and I have no knowledge in it, but you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful).

Comment: But EXTRA_NAME_ doesn't exist in DetailActivityFragment because I actually defined and initialized EXTRA_NAME_0, EXTRA_NAME_1, EXTRA_NAME_2 etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

replace

String EXTRA_NAME = "DetailActivityFragment.EXTRA_NAME_" + Integer.toString(i);

with,

String EXTRA_NAME = "DetailActivityFragment.EXTRA_NAME_" + i;

"+" this is concatenation, it inherently converts i to string.

Comment: I tried that before doing Integer.toString, didn't work!